# What regular expression in javascript should be used to match that a string contains no 2 dots together

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, pattern-matching

I need to check whether a string contains a dot in between or not, and if there are more than 2 dots than there should be any chracter (including special characters) between them.

`abc.def` should return true
`.abc.def` should return false 
`abc..def` should return false 
`abc.def.ghi` should return true
`abc` should return false
`abc.` should return false

Comment: I'm definitley not a regex expert but you probably want to do some research on lookaheads/lookbehinds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you are searching for is:

```
^[^.]+(\.[^.]+)+$
```

That consists of:

- `^`: begin of string
- `[^.]+`: at least one not-period.
- `(...)+`: at least one:

  - `\.`: literal period, followed by
  - `[^.]+`: at least one not-period
- `$`: end of string

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/y9F5Lt/1)